# Netbeans 11.2 GUI Palette Java persistence section missing

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I have upgraded Netbeans to 11.2 and while opening an old GUI project. I am noticing that the Java Persistence section of the palette is missing. 
I have tried reinstalling Netbeans and reset the windows.

Current view:
[image]

Comment: Hi Yogi, welcome to stackoverflow! In future pls write your text as a real question. Here I can only guess that the question would be "How can I show the persistence section?"

Comment: Hi Marco, you are right. I will keep that in mind.